# How do I add search box to a preview view in a list?

Tags: list-view, list-search-box

I have a user group who really likes the preview view of their list but also wants to be able to search the list.  I tried to convince them to use a metadata field to leverage the key filters but they want their field to be single line text.

When I create the preview view, we lose the "find a file" search box.  Any ideas on how to add that back?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you may have to tell them to change views to one that has the default style as it is the only style that has the "find a file" option. Other styles are historic to older versions of SharePoint from what it seems so the "find a file" was something that was only added to the "default" style from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Default style is the only view has the search box option. Otherwise I would create a light version of client-side solution to modify the Preview view for clients